# How to hide android's bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm really new in flutter and also in Android dev, but is it possible to hide the bottom navigation bar (see which item do i mean below) programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:
    `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);`

[Document](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fullscreen_mode)

Comment: Well i used this, but after that, i've got an blank white space.
And can't really put anything there.

Comment: Oh, this solved it.
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  appBar: new AppBar(),
);

Comment: While this is working but on some devices when we touch screen it displays that bottom navigation bar. Any guess how we can resolve that.

Comment: this seems to be deprecated

Comment: SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]) is not working for me. When touching the screen the bottom bar appears persistently.

Comment: @genericUser this happens to me too, any solutions?

Comment: Seems that flutter team does nothing about it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62412

Comment: SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays is depreciated. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326384/setenabledsystemuioverlays-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used-migrate-to-seten this link.

Comment: i think this is deprecated now

Comment: any method for hide permanent?

Answer (score 18):

*At the time of writing this answer all of the other posts here are outdated, using `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` will give a deprecation message.*

**To hide the system navigation bar or status bar** import:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

And use the service [SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiMode.html)

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
```

The function `setEnabledSystemUIMode` receives the `SystemUiMode` Enum which has the following options:

- **leanBack** - Fullscreen display with status and navigation bars presentable by tapping anywhere on the display.
- **immersive** - Fullscreen display with status and navigation bars presentable through a swipe gesture at the edges of the display.
- **immersiveSticky** - Fullscreen display with status and navigation bars presentable ***temporarly*** through a swipe gesture at the edges of the display.
- **edgeToEdge** - Fullscreen display with status and navigation elements rendered over the application.
- **manual** - Declares manually configured [SystemUiOverlay]s. (look at the docs for more information)

Comment: Helpful answer!

Answer (score 13):

For specifies the set of system overlays to have visible when the application
is running. you can use below static method:

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(List<SystemUiOverlay> overlays)
```

Examples :

1 - For **Hide bottom navigation** bar and **Still Status bar visible**

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

2 - For **Still bottom navigation visible** bar and **Hide Status bar**

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

3 - For **hide both** bottom Navigation and  Status bar

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

4 - For make **both visible**

```
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` to hide the status bar and the navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use this

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

in your `initState()`

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature is bugged in flutter, you can see this issue here.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62412

Normally you would need to do the following:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Coder's answer hides the buttons once, but if the user summons them again (by swiping up), the buttons stay visible.

#### How to hide the buttons on *app start* and *after the user summons them:*

From my testing, Flutter redraws everything from the root widget whenever buttons are summoned. That can be used to run a timer that hides the buttons every time the root widget is redrawn.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // hide android buttons when the app starts
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const immersiveModeDelaySeconds = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // every time the root widget is rebuilt, hide the buttons after n seconds.
    Timer(Duration(seconds: immersiveModeDelaySeconds), () {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
    });

    // run the rest of the app
    return MaterialApp(home: Container());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this method to hide the system navigation bar

1. import the services.dart package in your main.dart file

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
> ```

2. in your void main(){} add this

> ```
> void main(){
>
>   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>
>   SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: 
>   [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
>
>   runApp(const <Your App Name>());
>
> }
> ```