# setEnabledSystemUIOverlays is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Migrate to setEnabledSystemUIMode

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using the following code to show only status bar.

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([
  SystemUiOverlay.top
])
```

but it started giving me a warning:

> setEnabledSystemUIOverlays is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Migrate to setEnabledSystemUIMode.

So, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `setEnabledSystemUIMode` and provide `SystemUiMode.manual` as shown below:

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
  SystemUiOverlay.top
]);
```

You can also use `SystemUiMode`

1. Hide both overlays:

   ```dart
   SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
   ```
2. Show both overlays:

   ```dart
   SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
   ```

---

*But where to use this code?*

Consider placing it in `main()` for a global application effect, within `initState` for widget-specific behavior, or inside a callback for event-driven actions.

Comment: what happens if i pass empty list to overlays argument ?SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);

Comment: It will hide both , bottom overlay will be visible only  when swiping or touch the nav bar for few seconds .

Comment: Where to add this code? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: @iDecode iDecode, Thanks for response. I have solved this issue by updating flutter version with 3.14 and also upgraded a plugin/package. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 9):

Use setEnabledSystemUIMode instead of  setEnabledSystemUIOverlays.
Example:

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

change it to:

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Comment: I've already mentioned this thing in my answer. Sorry your code doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
```

It doesn't show up again after touching the screen