# How to disable android's bottom status bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Over the past few days, I've been struggling to figure out how to disable the Android device's bottom status (navigation) bar. (As shown in the image below)

[Bottom Status Bar on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wODYn.jpg)

I've looked everywhere and tried everything to find the solution. I tried every method there was to do this, but it didn't work the way I wanted it to. The system overlays, like the bottom and top status bars, can be hidden, but they cannot be entirely disabled or concealed.

I want to know if it is possible to completely disable the status bars. I'm building an app for a marketing MV Player device and the public users can touch or interact with the application but I have to prevent them from exiting the application for security reasons.

I have tried the method given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69326385/20511047). The bottom status bar, however, will be hidden; nonetheless, it will become visible if you swipe up to the position of the status bar, or occasionally when you press the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Nope. It is a major security concern when some app don't let user to navigate away to Home. Hence, it won't be ever implemented.

Comment: I suggest looking into Kiosk mode, this might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package `kiosk_mode` to do what you are after. Have a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_mode).

Comment: This package does the work, but not like the way I want it to work. As I mentioned before I want to completely prevent the user from exiting the application, but this package always shows a Snackbar message instructing the user on how to unpin (exit) the app, I couldn't find a way to disable this message in the package. Hence, this is not a solution.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But do update with information if / when you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but if you haven't found any solutions yet, i suggest looking into screen pinning:
https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138

And as mentioned in the link, these are the steps to do it:

**Turn on App Pinning**

- Open your phone's Settings app.
- Tap Security or Security & location
- Advanced  App pinning. If you can't find it, get help from your device manufacturer.
- Turn on App pinning.

When app pinning is on, you need to enter your PIN, pattern, or password before you can unpin.

**Pin a screen**

*After turning on app pinning:*

- Go to the screen you want to pin.
- Show the recent apps by swiping up or pressing the navigation button.
- Tap your app
- Tap Pin.

*If you're using Android 8.1 & below*

- Go to the screen you want to pin.
- Tap Overview.
- Swipe up to show the Pin.
- You'll see it at the bottom right of your selected screen.
- Tap the Pin.

**Unpin a screen**

Choose how to get around on your device. Learn how to get around on your Android phone. 
To unpin a screen:

- Gesture navigation: Swipe up and hold.
- 2-button navigation: Touch and hold Back and Home.
- 3-button navigation: Touch and hold Back and Overview.

If you're asked for your PIN, pattern, or password, enter it.

Note that this feature exists only in android lollipop and up.