# How do I remove this in my Flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter application, I want to remove this gestures footer. I have redmi phone. I don't want this to be visible in my app. Can I do this?[image]

Comment: I don't think that we can actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just another version of the bottom navigation bar:

[How to hide android's bottom navigation bar in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365173/how-to-hide-androids-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter)