# How to stretch bottom nav bar to take full height

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emgfg.png)

In the image, at the bottom, how do I fill it with bottom nav bar?

I don't know what it is called, so not able to search properly.

Comment: can you include your current  [minimal]snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52365173 hope this helps